# Warning message when generating STIX in Python

Tags: python, deprecation-warning

When running a simple example I get a warning I can't find the reason for.

```
from stix.core import STIXPackage, STIXHeader   # Import the STIX Package and STIX Header APIs

stix_package = STIXPackage()                    # Create an instance of STIXPackage
stix_header = STIXHeader()                      # Create an instance of STIXHeader
stix_header.description = "Getting Started!"    # Set the description
stix_package.stix_header = stix_header          # Link the STIX Head to our STIX Package

print(stix_package.to_xml())                    # print the XML for this STIX Package
```

Results in

**C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\stix\utils\deprecated.py:40: UserWarning: The use of this field has been deprecated. Received 'str' object.
  warnings.warn(msg)**

```
<stix:STIX_Package
        xmlns:cybox="http://cybox.mitre.org/cybox-2"
        xmlns:cyboxCommon="http://cybox.mitre.org/common-2"
        xmlns:cyboxVocabs="http://cybox.mitre.org/default_vocabularies-2"
        xmlns:example="http://example.com"
        xmlns:stix="http://stix.mitre.org/stix-1"
        xmlns:stixCommon="http://stix.mitre.org/common-1"
        xmlns:stixVocabs="http://stix.mitre.org/default_vocabularies-1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="example:Package-7e8da451-3a23-47dd-b2e1-8646200dadf0" version="1.2">
    <stix:STIX_Header>
        <stix:Description>Getting Started!</stix:Description>
    </stix:STIX_Header>
</stix:STIX_Package>
```

tips appreciated

Comment: What line of your code is in the stack trace

Comment: The warning appears after print(stix_package.to_xml())

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the stix bug tracker if no one answers here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `description` field is deprecated, as can be seen in the [docs](http://stix.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core/stix_header.html), which I reproduce here for posterity:

```
class stix.core.stix_header.STIXHeader(package_intents=None, description=None, handling=None, information_source=None, title=None, short_description=None)
Bases: stix.base.Entity

The STIX Package Header.

Parameters: 
handling – The data marking section of the Header.
information_source – The InformationSource section of the Header.
package_intents – DEPRECATED. A collection of VocabString defining the intent of the parent STIXPackage.
description – DEPRECATED. A description of the intent or purpose of the parent STIXPackage.
short_description – DEPRECATED. A short description of the intent or purpose of the parent STIXPackage.
title – DEPRECATED. The title of the STIXPackage.
```

I don't know why they haven't updated their example code yet.